# Trying to deactivate the automatic registration of RabbitListener instances so I can manually register my own

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-amqp

I am upgrading my Spring project from Spring 1.x up to (hopefully) 3.x. That said, I have just finished upgrading everything to 2.0.9 and now tried bumping to 2.1.18. There is an issue I am facing that, because I wanted to auto-register Rabbit queues / factories / listeners I have created a custom configuration class.

To achieve that I had to create a custom extension of RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor called ExtendedRabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor:

```
@Component
public class ExtendedRabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor extends
    RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor {

    public void processAmqpListener(RabbitListener rabbitListener, Method method, Object bean,
        String beanName) {
        super.processAmqpListener(rabbitListener, method, bean, beanName);
    }
}
```

so that I can have access to the protected processAmqpListener.
While this worked up to 2.0.9, in 2.1.18 it seems that Spring itself is registering the beans ahead of our registration which leads to the app breaking.

Is there any way I can deactivate the automatic registration of RabbitListeners from Spring's RabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor?

- I have tried creating custom CustomRabbitListener @interface so that the default BeanPostProcessor has nothing to register but that didn't work.
- I have tried setting the bean for the ExtendedRabbitListenerAnnotationBeanPostProcessor to @Primary so that it overwrites the Spring one but that doesn't work because it seems the Spring implementation loads its processor ahead of the registration of my bean (so primary does nothing.
  Edit: I have also tried removing the @EnableRabbit annotation but that deactivates everything on runtime as well.

Answer (score 0):

Name your bean `RabbitListenerConfigUtils.RABBIT_LISTENER_ANNOTATION_PROCESSOR_BEAN_NAME`

(`org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.internalRabbitListenerAnnotationProcessor`)

to override the default.

See `RabbitBootstrapConfiguration`.